# Enhanced Review Stats for Reviews

Tags: script, review

## SEReviewStats

Provides enhanced stats on the Stack Exchange Review pages Close, Reopen, Late Answers, First Posts & Low Quality Posts

#### Features

- Shows additional information on the Close, Reopen, Late Answers, First Posts & Low Quality Posts:

  - For questions reviews:

    - Gathers current close votes from question page.
    - Gathers total close votes, total reopen votes, close events & reopen events from admin timeline.
  - For answer reviews:

    - Gathers flags from admin timeline
    - Gathers current close votes from question page and displays it besides the question.
    - Gathers total close votes, total reopen votes, close events & reopen events from admin timeline and shows it at the question.

---

The data is shown in the side panels on the right as pictured below.

#### Questions

[image: Pictures that shows the additional stats on questions]

#### Answers

[image: Picture that shows the additional stats on answers]

#### Remarks

All information pulled from the admin timelines require mod permissions on the site.

#### Where to get it

It's on Github: [SEReviewStats](https://github.com/TheHelmar/SEReviewStats)

Comment: Isn’t `/posts/:id/timeline` available for everyone?

Comment: @JF it is, but the non-mod version doesn't hold the necessary information about close votes in the required detail.